# Add conditional dates to a column Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have the following Data Frame:

```
Frequency   Date 1          Date 2        Date 3
1        2020/04/20      2021/03/04     2020/03/04
1        2020/04/20      2021/03/04     0
1        2020/04/20      2021/03/04     0
2        2020/05/26      2021/08/04     2020/08/04
2        2020/05/26      2021/08/04     0
2        2020/05/26      2021/08/04     0
```

I would like to add months, but conditional on the number column: Thus:
If column number is 1, add 12 months.
If column number is 2, add 6 months.
If column number is 3, add 4 months.

In the rows that have 0 of the Data3 column, I need to add a year to the date of the previous row if the frequency column corresponds to 1. Add 6 months if the frequency row is 2. Without changing the values that are already assigned to the Data3 column (different from 0)

```
Frequency   Date 1          Date 2        Date 3
1        2020/04/20      2021/03/04     2020/03/04
1        2020/04/20      2021/03/04     2021/03/04
1        2020/04/20      2021/03/04     2022/03/04
2        2020/05/26      2021/08/04     2020/08/04
2        2020/05/26      2021/08/04     2021/02/04
2        2020/05/26      2021/08/04     2021/10/04
```

I have tried the following:

```
df['Date 3']=df.apply(lambda x:datetime(x['Date 1'].year+x['Frequency']-1,x['Date 2'].month,x['Date 2'].day),axis=1)
```

But it does not cover all conditions

Comment: What are you adding them to? The description doesn't clearly say what logic you want to implement.

Comment: In the rows that have 0 of the Data3 column, I need to add a year to the date of the previous row if the frequency column corresponds to 1. Add 6 months if the frequency row is 2. Without changing the values that are already assigned to the Data3 column (different from 0)

Comment: That's a great explanation! You should update the question with that comment to help people understand better.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your dataframe as such:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Frequency': {0: '1', 1: '1', 2: '1', 3: '2', 4: '2', 5: '2'},
 'Date 1': {0: '2020/04/20',
  1: '2020/04/20',
  2: '2020/04/20',
  3: '2020/05/26',
  4: '2020/05/26',
  5: '2020/05/26'},
 'Date 2': {0: '2021/03/04',
  1: '2021/03/04',
  2: '2021/03/04',
  3: '2021/08/04',
  4: '2021/08/04',
  5: '2021/08/04'},
 'Date 3': {0: '2020/03/04', 1: '0', 2: '0', 3: '2020/08/04', 4: '0', 5: '0'}})
```

Then converted the dtypes:

```
df['Date 1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date 1'])
df['Date 2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date 2'])
df['Date 3'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date 3'], errors='coerce')   # Makes the zeros into NaT values
df['Frequency'] = df['Frequency'].astype(int)
```

So, the steps below could be reduced so that there aren't as many intermediate steps, but I'll leave them in to make it easier to show the process.

Make a column we can use for grouping later. It uses the new `idx` column to identify where there are groups of consecutive missing dates.

```
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'idx'})
df.loc[ df['Date 3'].isna(), 'idx'] = np.nan
df['idx'] = df['idx'].fillna(method='ffill')

print(df)

   idx  Frequency     Date 1     Date 2     Date 3
0  0.0          1 2020-04-20 2021-03-04 2020-03-04
1  0.0          1 2020-04-20 2021-03-04        NaT
2  0.0          1 2020-04-20 2021-03-04        NaT
3  3.0          2 2020-05-26 2021-08-04 2020-08-04
4  3.0          2 2020-05-26 2021-08-04        NaT
5  3.0          2 2020-05-26 2021-08-04        NaT
```

Then add a helper column that converts your frequency into a number of months, set to zero in the rows where you don't need to manipulate the `Date 3`:

```
df['month_helper'] = 12//df['Frequency']
df.loc[ ~df['Date 3'].isna(), 'month_helper'] = 0
```

The number of months you'll want to offset the `Date 3` by is actually the cumulative sum of the offsets on the sequential missing dates, so we group by `idx` and take that `cumsum()`:

```
df['offset'] = df.groupby('idx')['month_helper'].cumsum()
```

Finally, we use that offset to update the `Date 3` column:

```
df['Date 3'] = df['Date 3'].fillna(method='ffill')
df['Date 3'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Date 3'] + pd.DateOffset(months=x['offset']), axis=1)

print(df)

   idx  Frequency     Date 1     Date 2     Date 3  month_helper  offset
0  0.0          1 2020-04-20 2021-03-04 2020-03-04             0       0
1  0.0          1 2020-04-20 2021-03-04 2021-03-04            12      12
2  0.0          1 2020-04-20 2021-03-04 2022-03-04            12      24
3  3.0          2 2020-05-26 2021-08-04 2020-08-04             0       0
4  3.0          2 2020-05-26 2021-08-04 2021-02-04             6       6
5  3.0          2 2020-05-26 2021-08-04 2021-08-04             6      12
```

Dropping the auxiliary columns yields what I think is your desired result...although the dataframe you posted has "2021/10/04" as the last value, which doesn't match the description:

```
df = df.drop(columns=['idx', 'month_helper','offset'])

print(df)

   Frequency     Date 1     Date 2     Date 3
0          1 2020-04-20 2021-03-04 2020-03-04
1          1 2020-04-20 2021-03-04 2021-03-04
2          1 2020-04-20 2021-03-04 2022-03-04
3          2 2020-05-26 2021-08-04 2020-08-04
4          2 2020-05-26 2021-08-04 2021-02-04
5          2 2020-05-26 2021-08-04 2021-08-04
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a straight way to do it :

The database (sorry, I've made a quick one)

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['freq'] = [1,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2]
df['col1'] = pd.date_range("1983-03-01","1983-12-31",freq="1M")
df['col2'] = pd.date_range("1983-03-01","1983-12-31",freq="1M")
df['col3'] = pd.date_range("1983-03-01","1983-12-31",freq="1M")
df.loc[3,'col3'] = None
df.loc[4,'col3'] = None
df.loc[5,'col3'] = None
df.loc[8,'col3'] = None
df
```

[image]

And the code :

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset
_condition1 = df.col3.isnull()
_condition2 = df.freq == 1
_condition3 = df.freq == 2
while df.col3.isnull().any():
    df['col3'] = np.where(_condition1&_condition2,(df.col3.shift(1)+pd.DateOffset(years=1)),np.where(_condition1&_condition3,(df.col3.shift(1)+pd.DateOffset(months=6)),df.col3))
df
```

[image]

EDIT : I've edited the code because I first missed the case of several NaT in consecutive rows. Thanks to Rick M for that

Comment: Your solution works if there are no places where `Date 3` is NaT for sequential entries, but if there are 2 or more NaT values in a row (as there are in the original example) it will only fill in the first NaT it finds in each "group". You *could* run your code multiple times in a row until there aren't any more NaT values in the column, but it will slow down a little if there are any long runs of NaTs in a row. Good idea to explicitly call out the freq = 1 and 2 cases; that is simpler than what I did with `12//x` if there really are only a limited number of frequencies to consider.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thanks to you, I've missed that case due to my laziness. I should have reproduced the database as you did. ;) I edit the code
I try to code with simple and explicit sequences in OS, to show in the same time the logical of it. Because all the readers are not always comfortable with code yet.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer to end this thread, other community members can benefit from it.